# Please correct this python script to send data on USB0 port?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from serial import Serial
from time import sleep

class Create:
        
    def __init__(self, tty="/dev/ttyUSB0"):
        
        self.timeout = 5
        self.port = Serial(tty, 57600, timeout= self.timeout)
                

    def start(self):
        
        
        self.__sendNow(P,0,0,0)
        sleep(1)
        self.__sendNow(V,0,0,100)
        sleep(10)


    def stop(self):
        
        self.__sendNow(V,0,0,0)
```

/home/admin-pc/mywork/test/scripts/create.py: line 1: This module provides a class wrapping an Exia.: command not found 
from: can't read /var/mail/serial
from: can't read /var/mail/time 
/home/admin-pc/mywork/test/scripts/create.py: line 6: class: command not found
/home/admin-pc/mywork/test/scripts/create.py: line 7: Wrapper class for the iRobot Create: command not found 
/home/admin-pc/mywork/test/scripts/create.py: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('/home/admin-pc/mywork/test/scripts/create.py: line 9:`  def **init**(self, tty="/dev/ttyUSB0"):'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71104/please-correct-this-python-script-to-send-data-on-usb0-port?/) by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 205 on 2013-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you viewers, I found the mistake and corrected it ....

this is just deceleration of class there is no command to write data on USB port.

there is just two line code to do the same

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS1', 19200, timeout=1)
ser.write('5')
```

---

Originally posted by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) with karma: 205 on 2013-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0